# When inserting a parent and its children can Hibernate set the parent id when inserting the child rather than having to update after?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have two objects

```
public class Parent {
    int id;
    String name;
    int Set<Child> children;
}

public class Child {
    int id;
    String name;
    int parentId;
}
```

With the following mapping file

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="Parent" table="parent">
        <id column="id" access="field">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>    
        <property name="name" column="name" access="field" />    
        <set name="children" access="property" cascade="all" lazy="true"  >
            <key><column name="parent_id"/></key>
            <one-to-many class="com.hp.autonomy.corepolicy.common.dto.LexiconExpression"/>
        </set>
    </class>
    <class name="Child" table="child">
        <id column="id" access="field">
            <generator class="identity"/>
        </id>    
        <property name="name" column="name" access="field" />            
        <property name="parentId" column="parent_id" access="field" not-null="true" />
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I save a parent with one child the sql generated looks like

> Hibernate: insert into parent (id, name) values (null, ?)
>
> Hibernate: insert into child (id, parent_id, name) values (null, ?, ?)
>
> Hibernate: update child set parent_id=? where id=?

It seems like when hibernate inserts the child it sets the parent_id to null and then comes and updates it after. This causes problems in my database and hibernate validation, as the schema says that parent_id cannot be null.

Is it possible to have the second insert statement use the parent_id created when inserting the parent rather than coming along later and updating the child?

Comment: Can you post the java code doing the insert?

Comment: I'm guessing its because you don't have bidirectional mapping. You never specified a manyToOne mapping in the child class on the join column. Try that and let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change

```
<property name="parentId" column="parent_id" access="field" not-null="true" />
```

By

```
<many-to-one name="parent" class="change to the parent classname">
     <column name="parent_id" not-null="true" access="field"/>
</many-to-one>
```

You will need to change the `Child` class to have a `parent` member instead of the `parentId` and update the config above accordingly.

Comment: Is there no way to do this without changing the class definition for Parent and Child?

Comment: How to do this using annotation?